# Does eating food which was exposed to *ionizing* EM radiation pose a health risk?

Tags: nutrition, radiation

From what I've read, non-ionizing EM radiation is harmless. There is little evidence that it causes any health issues. This is also the consensus here on Skeptics, that's the case in [mobile phone related questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and [microwave related questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=microwave).

So let's assume that cooking food with non-ionizing radation is safe.

**Which leads to my question:**

Does eating food which was exposed to **ionizing** EM radiation pose a health risk? The DNA material found in that food would most likely be seriously damaged, but does that even matter? Human food is in essence a dead organism. A dead DNA will not be active, it will not reproduce nor generate any proteins even when damaged. In the worst case scenario, we'd just eat a dead cancerous cell.

At least that's my theory. Enlighten me!

This also leads to a highly related sub-question: Is eating dead cancerous cells dangerous?

**Possible answers that refute my theory:**

- Eating dead cancerous cells is dangerous.
- Ionizing radiation has some dangerous effects beyond crippling the DNA
  of the food.
- The DNA is still somewhat active, even in a dead organism.
- Other.

Comment: Can someone find a notable claim that eating such food is harmless/harmful so we can bring this on-topic?

Comment: How about this: http://www.organicconsumers.org/irradlink.cfm

Comment: Or this one for the other side of the argument: http://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm261680.htm

Comment: People *do* believe that putting food through ionizing radiation makes it dangerous.

Comment: @Articuno I agree they do. So it shouldn't be too hard to reference such a claim in the question. That is our usual standard.

Comment: @matt_black Our standard does not require a reference to such a claim. Our standard is simply whether a bunch of people believe the claim.

Comment: @Articuno Fair point, but we *usually* like to see references.

Comment: Highly related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20707/is-it-possible-for-ingested-dsrna-or-other-genetic-materials-to-affect-human-g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **United States General Accounting Office** wrote in a [Report to Congressional Requesters](http://www.gao.gov/archive/2000/rc00217.pdf) in 2000:

> Scientific studies conducted by public and private researchers worldwide
>   over the past 50 years support the benefits of food irradiation while
>   indicating minimal potential risks. For example, an expert committee convened by the World Health Organization reviewed the findings of over
>   500 studies and concluded that food irradiation creates no toxicological,
>   microbiological, or nutritional problems. Cited benefits of food irradiation
>   include (1) reducing foodborne pathogens; (2) extending the shelf life of
>   some fruits and vegetables by preventing sprouting, deactivating mold, and
>   killing bacteria; and (3) controlling insect pests—thus reducing the need
>   for environmentally harmful fumigants. These studies have not borne out
>   concerns about the safety of consuming irradiated foods. For example, the
>   studies indicated that chemical compounds in irradiated food are generally
>   the same as those in cooked foods, and any differences do not put
>   consumers at risk. As for nutritional quality, the main components of
>   food—carbohydrates, protein, and fats—undergo minimal change during
>   irradiation, and vitamin loss corresponds to that in foods that are cooked,
>   canned, or held in cold storage.